# How to display an String type array of Java in xsl?

Tags: java, arrays, xml, xslt, xpath

Below is the xml file from which the xpath is to be framed and used in xsl file.

```
<response>
<RetrieveUserResponseDTO>
<mob />
<idCustomer />
<requestId />
<idChannel />
<userType />
<idUser />
<idChannelUser>123</idChannelUser>
<idChannelUser>234</idChannelUser>
<idChannelUser>1245</idChannelUser>
```

etc

Below is the Java String array

```
l_resp.idChannelUser = new String[3];
```

Below is the xsl code

```
<xsl:for-each select="faml/response/retrieveuserresponsedto/idchanneluser">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="warning" width="75%">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="faml/response/retrieveuserresponsedto/idchanneluser"></xsl:value-of>
                                                </td>       
                                            </tr>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Your XSLT refers to a `faml` element, but this is not shown in your XML. Is this correct? Also, I don't think the java array is relevant here, as XSLT wouldn't be able to access that. Are you simply using the java array to generate XML in this case, which is then processed by XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the bit about the Java array, and focusing only on XSLT transforming XML, there are two issues two note

1. XML and XSLT are case-sensitive so `retrieveuserresponsedto` is not going to match `RetrieveUserResponseDTO` in your XML (and `idchanneluser` will not match `idChannelUser`)
2. In side your `xsl:for-each` statement, you will be positioned on an `idChannelUser` element, so your XPath to get the value needs to be relative to that.

Try this XSLT instead: (You might need to add a `faml` element at the start of the XPath if indeed that element is present in your XML)

```
<xsl:for-each select="response/RetrieveUserResponseDTO/idChannelUser">
   <tr>
      <td class="warning" width="75%">
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </td>       
   </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim C. It worked. Yes what ever you have edited to my post is correct, just to brief the post I have posted like that way. One question to you what that "." means in select attribute <xsl:value-of select="." /> please explain to me.

Comment: A full-stop `.` represents the current node, so `<xsl:value-of select="." />` means show the value of the node you are currently on. In this case, you are positioned on the `idChannelUser` node, so it will output the value of that.

Comment: Thanks you once again